# how to parse this as it gives me dotted array which i can't access amadeus?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

[image]

This is the results, I've got after requesting flight of Amadeus APIand I can't access the innermost values of the array as it give me the dots in the screen shot any help?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also could you please post the actual JSON code in the question rather than a picture?

Comment: Even if there are "dots in the screen", accessing that data should be possible. That's only a way of shortening the output, not something persistent in the data structure

Comment: @NicoHaase yes it wasn't presistent in the datastructure that what i realized as i can access the data now thanks

Comment: @DavidRogers thanks it's now resolved

Comment: Excellent, Thanks for posting your answer, however could you mark your answer as accepted(Green Check Mark), maybe provide a bit more detail too :)

Answer (score 0):

it was only shortening the output by the dd function in laravel but the data is still accessible Thanks